# How can I hide null-values but show the number 0 when displaying the amounts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written the following function:

```
  /**
   * Transform values
   * @param val number
   * @return val.toLocalString()
   */
  public transformAmount(val: number) {
    if (val === null || !val) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 1, minimumFractionDigits: 1 });
    }
  }
```

In the function, I display the amounts with one decimal place and zero-values are left blank. What do I have to change in my code so that the number 0 is also displayed?

Comment: Because 0 is treated as falsy you have to add a explicit case for 0. Adding `&& val != 0` to your if-clause should do

Comment: an example would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operators. If `val` is null or undefined, `?.` will return undefined and `??` will return `''`.

```
public transformAmount(val: number) {
  return val?.toLocaleString(...) ?? '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0 is treated as false, so it will pass the first condition in your code, thus returning the value empty string.
You have to write something like this;

```
public transformAmount(val: number) {
    if (val === null || val === undefined) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 1, minimumFractionDigits: 1 });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, i see the `val` should be a number (include 0), so you can check if `val` is number:

```
  /**
   * Transform values
   * @param val number
   * @return val.toLocalString()
   */
  public transformAmount(val: number) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(val))) { // returns true if val is not a number
      return '';
    } else {
      return val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 1, minimumFractionDigits: 1 });
    }
  }
```